# C++ 11 std::thread in cycles

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have a cycle in C++11 like that:

```
while (true) 
{
    std::thread t0(some_work, 0);
    ...
    std::thread tn(some_work, n);
    t0.join();
    ...
    tn.join();
}
```

but creating new threads in every iteration isn't good of course. In C it's easy to use messages to tell threads to wait another iteration, but I want to do it with C++11 tools. I looked at `condition_variable`, but it isn't solution I think. What can I do with it?

Answer (score 1):

## Use Boost to get through!

Note: I do not have C++11, so the code I will show you is for C++98 with [`Boost libraries`](http://www.boost.org/). Most of Boost stuff ends up in `std::tr1` and subsequently later versions of the standard, so most of this is probably transferrable without boost.

It sounds like you have multiple threads that you are constantly, but not consistently, assigning work to do. The work doesn't always need performing (otherwise your thread could do it in its own loop) or perhaps the thread doesn't have the information to perform it. If this is the case, consider [`boost::asio::io_service`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html).

With this, you will need to create a thread that is always running, so you'll probably want to put your threads in a class (although you don't need to).

```
class WorkerThread
{
    WorkerThread()
    : thread(&WorkerThread::HandleWorkThread, this), io_service(), runThread(true)
    {
    }
    ~WorkerThread()
    {
        // Inform the thread not to run anymore:
        runThread = false;
        // Wait for the thread to finish:
        thread.join();
    }
    void AssignWork(boost::function<void()> workFunc) { io_service.post(workFunc); }
private:
    void HandleWorkThread()
    {
        while (runThread)
        {
            // handle work:
            io_service.run();
            // prepare for more work:
            io_service.reset();
        }
    }

    boost::thread thread;
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    bool runThread; // NB: this should be atomic
};
```

Now you can have the following:

```
void CalculateThings(int, int);
void CalculateThingsComplex(int, int, double);

// Create two threads. The threads will continue to run and wait for work to do
WorkerThread thread1, thread2;
while (true)
{
    thread1.AssignWork(boost::bind(&CalculateThings, 20, 30));
    thread2.AssignWork(boost::bind(&CalculateThingsComplex, 2, 5, 3.14));
}
```

You can continue to assign as much work as necessary. Once the `WorkerThread`s go out of scope, they will stop running and close nicely

Comment: Hmm I have a problem because I want mainstream to call some func(like apply_changes();) after all threads will finish their works, so I need smth like messages maybe